# Get single property of item in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the success callback of an ajax request, I get one object, which is an array of objects (`poList`).  I want to loop through this list and if the `status` property is something, then do something.

In the example below, `response.PoList` is a valid array object with two items in it and `x` is `0` (in the debugger, I can hover over PoList and it works); however, the `status` is doesn't exist (i.e., this if statement is always false).  What am I doing wrong here

```
for (var x = 0; x < response.PoList.length; x++) {
    if (response.PoList[x].Status == 'Not edited') {
        response.PoList[x].StatusNum = 1;
    } else {
        response.PoList[x].StatusNum = 3
    }
}
```

**Edit**

See screenshot below, I don't think it's a case-sensitivity issue.  So, what's highlighted is `response.PoList` (not just `response`), `x` is currently `0`, and if I hover over `Status`, I get nothing (no "`undefined`" tooltip or anything)

[image]

Comment: You use two different capitalization styles in your post and code for poList and status. javascript is case-sensitive. Is it a capitalization problem?

Comment: The for loop looks right. It could be worth checking if Status property exists before checking its value.

Comment: Added the screenshot, I don't *believe* it's a case sensitivity issue, just an oversight when I was typing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works as provided - what depends is whether it actually matches your data.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4juzL/1/)

I made this example based on your code. If your response object is different, then, yes, you're doing something wrong.

Also, I'd echo [Mr. Zimmerman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708648/get-single-property-of-item-in-javascript-array/20708821#comment31018992_20708648); this could easily be a capitalization issue.

```
response = {
    PoList: [
        { 
            foo: 'bar',
            Status: 'edited'
        },
        { 
            foo: 'baz',
            Status: 'Not edited'
        },
        { 
            foo: 'barbar',
            Status: 'Not edited'
        }
    ]
};

for (var x = 0; x < response.PoList.length; x++) {
    if (response.PoList[x].Status === 'Not edited') {
        response.PoList[x].StatusNum = 1;
    } else {
        response.PoList[x].StatusNum = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting... I feel like mine is doing just that, but it's not working the same.

Comment: Can you paste in the exact response object you're dealing with to your question? (Just use JSON.stringify() on it to get a copyable version.)

Comment: Yeah, your code is working fine on the response you just pasted, Tom. [My updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4juzL/2/) has the second item duplicated, but with the Status property changed to 'Not edited', just like in your code, and it properly sets the StatusNum to 1.

Comment: Very weird!  I'll see if I can put together a broken fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the existance of `response.PoList[x].Status`:

```
for (var x = 0; x < response.PoList.length; x++) {
  if (response.PoList[x].Status && response.PoList[x].Status == 'Not edited') {
    response.PoList[x].StatusNum = 1;
  } else {
    response.PoList[x].StatusNum = 3
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THNy9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon here `response.PoList[x].StatusNum = 3`. Other than that, I don't see anything wrong with the code provided, so `PoList`'s variable `Status` must not be set in the response.